# CSS On Hover change div before it and after it

Tags: html, css, hover

I have two divs, one after another but float side by side, one is of a button img type thing and the other is some words associated with the what the button is. They are about 20px apart on screen.

What I want to happen is that when you hover over the button it changes and also changes the text, this I can do using the "+" operator in the css file, however I also want when you hover the text for the button to change, this isn't possible with the + as the text div is after the one with the img.

Below is my html and css, is there any simple way to do this? I don't want to really be using javascript and such to do it so if it requires major things I won't bother.

I just realized that I changed a few things before asking the question and it doesn't actually work with the + either

I have added a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/LzLyK/1/

Basically when you hover the square it turns green, when you hover the text it turns green, what I want is to hover the square and square and test turns green and if you hover the text the square and text turns green

**HTML**

```
<div class="services-section-holder">
    <a href="#"><div class="services-section-img"></div></a>
    <div class="services-section-title"><p><a href="#">Exhibition</a></p></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.services-section-holder{
    position:relative;
    width:270px;
    height:70px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.services-section-img{
    position:relative;
    width:80px;
    height:75px;
    float:left;
    background:url(../images/greycircle.jpg);
}
.services-section-title{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height:75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    padding-left:20px;
}
.services-section-title a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.services-section-title a {
    color:#000;
}
.services-section-title a:hover {
    color:#906;
}
.services-section-img:hover {
    background:url(../images/greycirclehover.jpg);
}
.services-section-img:hover + .services-section-title a{
    color:#906;
}
```

Comment: Always add a fiddle demo with this sort of questions, for quick solutions

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're trying to ascend then descend the DOM with CSS which cannot work, CSS selectors can only work on identifying siblings or descendants.

Either wrap the initial `a` in its child `div` so both your `divs` are at the same level, or move `class="services-section-img"` from the `div` to its parent `a`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/jyXLt/)

[**Example fiddle of working solution/logic vs your current code**](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/jyXLt/1/)

Again, CSS cannot ascend the DOM so any adjacency selectors only work by identifying elements *following* the initially specified element.

Comment: I have an img in the background not text which is why im using ahref outside the div, is there another way to do this? and i need to hover over either div and both change, not just hover over the first and the second changes, what you have got is what i started with before fiddling around to try and get what i want

Comment: @snookian - I didnt know what you previously had, you'll need to implement a JS or jQuery solution as this kind of selection cannot be done in vanilla CSS